# Fill container with divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm filling the `body` with divs that have specific width and height. Then I get the width of this group of boxes. I use this width to center this group with CSS ( `margin: 0 auto` ). My problem is that I'm getting an extra row always that doesn't have the same number of divs.

Here's my code.

HTML:

```
<body>
<!-- Container-->
<div id="container_boxes" class="clearfix"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#container_boxes{
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 5px;
}

.box{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box:hover{
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);   
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        while( $(window).height() > $("#container_boxes").height() && $(window).width() > $("#container_boxes").width()) {
            $("#container_boxes").append("<div class=\"box\"></div>");

        }

        colors= ['#bdc3c7', '#7f8c8d', '#95a5a6', '#2c3e50', '#34495e'];
        $('.box').each(function(){
            var rndmclr = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
            $(this).css('background-color', rndmclr);
        });

        function boxesNumbers(){
            var num_boxes = 0;
            $('.box').each(function(){
                if($(this).prev().length > 0){
                    if($(this).position().top != $(this).prev().position().top) return false;
                        num_boxes++;
                } else {
                    num_boxes++;
                }
            });
            $('#container_boxes').css('width', num_boxes*260);
        };

        boxesNumbers();
        $(window).resize(boxesNumbers);

    });
```

Thanks

Comment: please create a fiddle, and be more specific about what you want to happen.

Comment: I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/BqBnt/) and I let it run for a while, but it never stopped.

Comment: I'm trying to make a fiddle, but it keeps crashing, there's something wrong with the 'while' loop. @andi, what i'm trying to do is to fill the `body` with squares, but the `body` depends on the size of the window. With the code that is above, i achieved to fill the body, but there's always an extra row that doesn't have the same number of squares as the previous rows. I don't want this extra row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I understand what you are going for.  Here is the working fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/6NLjU/

I did two things in addition to your code.

1) Added a clearfix on the container div, so that it would always have a height even though you are floating the inner boxes.

```
#container_boxes:after {content:""; display:table; clear:both;}
```

2) After the while loop finishes, remove the last box.  This is because the loop doesn't know that it has exceeded the window size until it adds a box which doesn't fit and then sees that the container is too big.  So afterwards, I removed that one box that didn't fit.

```
$("#container_boxes .box:last-child").remove();
```